# Passing Project parameter to dtexec

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis, ssis-2012, dtexec

My SSIS package has a project parameter called SMTPServer.
I pass that parameter like below when executing dtexec:

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\dtexec" /Server 
{myDBServer} /ISServer "\SSISDB\mySSIS.dtsx"  /Par 
"$Project::SMTPServer";\""Smtp.my.smtp-server"\"
```

But, I am getting the error:

> Option "$Project::SMTPServer;Smtp.my.smtp-server" is not valid.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think it is a quotation order issue, check my answer update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Trying to figure out the issue

**(1) Try fixing the the quotations:**

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\dtexec" /Server 
{myDBServer} /ISServer "\SSISDB\mySSIS.dtsx"  /Par 
"$Project::SMTPServer";"Smtp.my.smtp-server"
```

Or

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\dtexec" /Server 
{myDBServer} /ISServer "\SSISDB\mySSIS.dtsx"  /Par 
"$Project::SMTPServer";"\"Smtp.my.smtp-server\""
```

**(2) Or Without the quotations:**

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\dtexec" /Server 
{myDBServer} /ISServer "\SSISDB\mySSIS.dtsx"  /Par 
"$Project::SMTPServer";Smtp.my.smtp-server
```

**(3) Or try to use `/SET` option:** *(not sure if this will works in this case)*

```
"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\dtexec" /Server 
{myDBServer} /ISServer "\SSISDB\mySSIS.dtsx"  /SET 
\Package.Variables[$Project::SMTPServer];\""Smtp.my.smtp-server"\"
```

**Related Links**

- [DTEXEC.exe /Set Project.params in Project Deployment Model](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/5d8644d3-3235-41dc-9e16-bbe98fceac6a/dtexecexe-set-projectparams-in-project-deployment-model?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017)
- [DTEXEC Command Line Parameters Using Command Files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1812/dtexec-command-line-parameters-using-command-files/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Turns out I forgot to add /par before
"$Project::SMTPServer";\""Smtp.my.smtp-server"\"